# When do total and partial derivatives commute?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

In Classical Mechanics, the Lagrangian is a function of a generalized coordinate $q$, the corresponding generalized velocity $\dot{q}$, and time $t$.

For the Lagrangian, $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} \neq \frac{\partial \dot{L}}{\partial \dot{q}},$$ that is, the two derivatives do not commute. However, what if $L$ were a function only of $q$ and $t$? Then would the total derivative in $t$ and the partial derivative in $q$ always commute?

Also, for $L(q, t)$,  is $\frac{\partial \dot{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}$ always equal to $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$?

Answer (score 2):

Take into account that, for a function $f$ of $q,\dot{q},t,$ the total derivative is given by
$$
\frac{d}{dt}=\sum_{h=1}^n\left(\dot{q}_h\frac{\partial}{\partial{q_h}}+\ddot{q}_h\frac{\partial}{\partial{\dot{q}_h}}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}
$$
If $f$ only depends on $q,t$ then
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\frac{\partial}{\partial{q_k}}\frac{df}{dt}
  &=\frac{\partial}{\partial{q_k}}\left[\sum_{h=1}^n\left(\dot{q}_h\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{q_h}}+\cancel{\ddot{q}_h\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\dot{q}_h}}}\right)+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}\right]=\\
  &=\sum_{h=1}^n\left(\dot{q}_h\frac{\partial}{\partial{q_h}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{q_k}}+\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{q_k}}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{q_k}}
\end{align}
Note that the two derivatives commute also if $f$ depends on $\dot{q}.$
Also, for $\partial\dot{L}/\partial\dot{q}$ and $\partial{L}/\partial{q}$ when $L$ does not depend on $\dot{q},$ while the former is zero, the latter in general is not.

Comment: How come $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_k}(\dot{q_h}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_h})=\dot{q}_h\frac{\partial}{\partial q_h}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_k}$? I can see commuting partials being useful eventually, but how do we know that $\dot{q}_h$ does not depend on $q_k$?

Comment: @ShadyPuck they are independent variable, like in $y'' = f(x,y,y')$ you can obtain by derivation $y''' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y' +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}y''$

Answer (score 0):

In general a Lagrangian $L$ that depends on
functions $\phi:M\to N$ and their $k$ derivatives, i.e. a function
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
\begin{equation}
  L:J^k(M,N) \to \R
\end{equation}
can be written in local coordinates as
\begin{align}
  L(j^k_x\phi)
  &=
  L(x,\phi_{i}(x),\phi_{i,\mu}(x),\phi_{i,\mu\nu}(x),\dots,\phi_{i,\mu_1\dots\mu_k}(x))
  \\
  &= L(x^{\mu},\phi_{i,(\alpha)}(x)).
\end{align}
where the indices after the commas represent partial derivatives and $(\alpha)$ represents a list of indices of size $\geq 0$.
The total derivative along the $\mu$-th coordinate in $M$ is the
operator
\begin{equation}
  \frac{dL}{dx^{\mu}}
  =
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^{\mu}}
  +
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_{i}}\phi_{i,\mu}
  +
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_{i,\nu}}\phi_{i,\nu\mu}
  +
  \dots
  +
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial
  \phi_{i,\nu_1\dots\nu_k}}\phi_{i,\nu_1\dots\nu_k\mu}
.\end{equation}
we abreviate this as
\begin{equation}
  \frac{dL}{dx^{\mu}}
  =
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^{\mu}}
  +
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_{i,(\alpha)}}\phi_{i,(\alpha)\mu}
\end{equation}
where the repeated indices imply sum.
Then for any list of indices $(\alpha)$ we get
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}}\frac{dL}{dx^{\mu}}
  &= \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}}
  \left(
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^{\mu}}
    + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_{j,(\beta)}}
    \phi_{j,(\beta)\mu}
  \right) \\
  &=
    \frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}\partial x^{\mu}}
    +
    \frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}\partial \phi_{j,(\beta)}}
    \phi_{j,(\beta)\mu}
    +
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_{j,(\beta)}}
    \frac{\partial \phi_{j,(\beta)\mu}}{\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}}
  \\
  &=
    \left(
    \frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial x^{\mu}\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}}
    +
    \frac{\partial^{2} L}{\partial \phi_{j,(\beta)}\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}}
    \phi_{j,(\beta)\mu}
    \right)
    +
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_{j,(\beta)}}
    \delta^{i}_j\delta^{(\alpha)}_{(\beta)\mu}
    \\
  &=
    \frac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}}
    +
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_{i,(\beta)}}
    \delta^{(\alpha)}_{(\beta)\mu}
.\end{align}
So the operators $\frac{d}{dx^{\mu}}$ and
$\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}}$ don't quite commute, but
almost. The difference is
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial }{\partial \phi_{i,(\alpha)}}\frac{dL}{dx^{\mu}}
  -
  \frac{d}{dx^{\mu}}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi_{i,(\alpha)}}
  =
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_{i,(\beta)}}
  \delta^{(\alpha)}_{(\beta)\mu}
.\end{equation}
This makes clear that the operators fail to commute exactly when
$(\alpha)=(\beta)\mu$ for some list of indices $(\beta)$ such that
$L$ depends on $\phi_{i,(\beta)}$.
I.e., whenever the variable $\phi_{i,(\alpha)}$ is the $\mu$-th
derivative of a variable $\phi_{i,(\beta)}$ upon which $L$ depends.

For example, for $M=\R$ and $N=\R^{3}$, take
\begin{equation}
  L(t,\phi_{i}(t),\dot\phi_{i}(t)) = \frac{m}{2}\|\dot\phi(t)\|^{2} -
  V(\phi_3(t))
.\end{equation}
Then since the $\dot\phi_i$ appear in $L$, the derivatives
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial }{\partial\ddot\phi_i}\frac{dL}{dt}
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\ddot\phi_i}
\end{equation}
won't match up.
Also, since $L$ depends on $\phi_3$, the derivatives
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial }{\partial\dot\phi_3}\frac{dL}{dt}
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot\phi_3}
\end{equation}
won't agree, but all the other derivatives will commute.